# How to use 'mask' in Pandas for multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

For instance, I have 20 columns in dataset, but replace of negative values is required only for two columns. How do I do? For instance, for ArrDelay and DepDelay.

Dataset:

```
FlightNum ArrDelay DepDelay TailNum Month Dest
3232 3 -6 432G 1 ORX
4342 -2 4 476N 2 TOL
6344 -1 -4 643G 3 JFK
7564 5 13 653A 4 CVO
```

The result should be:

```
FlightNum ArrDelay DepDelay TailNum Month Dest
3232 3 0 432G 1 ORX
4342 0 4 476N 2 TOL
6344 0 0 643G 3 JFK
7564 5 13 653A 4 CVO
```

I can't use general 'mask' for all values because there are some columns with 'string' values and then errors are shown. But if I use 'mask' only for ArrDelay or DepDelay, everything works good. But it's required to remove negative values simultaneously for both columns.

My code:

```
data = data.mask(data.ArrDelay.lt(0),0) #how to add 'DepDelay'?
data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
data = data.assign(
    ArrDelay=np.where(data["ArrDelay"].lt(0), 0, data["ArrDelay"]),
    DepDelay=np.where(data["DepDelay"].lt(0), 0, data["DepDelay"])
)
print(data)

   FlightNum  ArrDelay  DepDelay TailNum  Month Dest
0       3232         3         0    432G      1  ORX
1       4342         0         4    476N      2  TOL
2       6344         0         0    643G      3  JFK
3       7564         5        13    653A      4  CVO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns to update, [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) the values lower than 0, and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame in place.

```
cols = ['ArrDelay', 'DepDelay']
df.update(df[cols].clip(lower=0))
```

Alternative if you prefer a mask:

```
df.update(df[cols].mask(df[cols].lt(0), 0))
```

Output:

```
   FlightNum  ArrDelay  DepDelay TailNum  Month Dest
0       3232         3         0    432G      1  ORX
1       4342         0         4    476N      2  TOL
2       6344         0         0    643G      3  JFK
3       7564         5        13    653A      4  CVO
```